# Insert element inside HTML video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

How can I add some dynamic elements inside html5 video?
For example: I have a video that is streamed, and I would like to follow faces framed by a transparent square.
How can I add that square?

Comment: I'd say thats beyond the scope of the HTML5 video spec as you would have to process the video. For sure you can lay elements over the video, but tracking of faces is not possible.

Comment: Maybe something with AngularJS, some library or canvas?